# compareTo and insert sort

Tags: c#

Not only am I new to programming, but sorting algorithms as well. I am in an algorithm and design analysis class so I am understanding the concepts better because of that... until this problem.

My insert sort will not work. Because this is generic I have to do a lot comparing it seems (or maybe that is just the way I wrote the code). So, it gives me this error on the temp = list[i] and also in my while loop "Operator > cannot be applied to operands of type T and int and Cannot implicitly convert type T to int. Can someone please explain to me why the compareto I used did not solve this problem. Also, please explain in detail so I can learn it. Am I needing to compare both temp and j? I could not figure that out.

```
using System;

namespace ArrayListNamespace
{
public abstract class ArrayList<T> where T : IComparable
{
    protected T[] list;
    protected int length;

    public ArrayList()
    {
        list = new T[100];
        length = 0;
    }

    public abstract void insert(ref T item);

    public int remove(ref T item)
    {
        if (length == 0) return 0;
        else
        {
            //find value, if it exists
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                if (item.Equals(list[i]))
                {
                    list[i] = list[length - 1];
                    length--;
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
    }
    public void print()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
        }
    }
    public void removeAll(ref T item)
    {
        for (; ; )
        {
            int r = remove(ref item);
            if (r == -1) break;
        }
    }

    public T min(ref T item)
    {
        T tempItem = list[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if (list[i].CompareTo(tempItem) < 0)
            {
                tempItem = list[i];
            }
        }
        return tempItem;
    }

    public T max(ref T item)
    {
        T tempItem = list[0];

        for (int i = 0; i > length; i++)
        {
            if (list[i].CompareTo(tempItem) < 0)
            {
                tempItem = list[i];
            }
        }
        return tempItem;
    }

    public void insertSort()
    {
        int temp, j;

        for (int i = 1; i < length; i++)
        {
           if (list[i].CompareTo(temp) < 0)
            {
                temp = list[i];
                j = i - 1;
                while (j >= 0 && list[j] > temp)
                {
                    list[j + 1] = list[j];
                    j--;
                }
                list[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using UnorderedArrayListNamespace;

namespace test
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UnorderedArrayList<int> u = new UnorderedArrayList<int>();
        Console.WriteLine("This is the list before removal...");
        u.print();
        int var = 5;
        u.insert(ref var);
        var = 12;
        u.insert(ref var);
        var = 2;
        u.insert(ref var);
        var = 5;
        u.insert(ref var);
        var = 29;
        u.insert(ref var);
        var = 33;
        u.insert(ref var);
        var = 31;
        u.insert(ref var);
        var = 7;
        u.insert(ref var);
        var = 13;
        u.insert(ref var);


        u.print();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("This is the list after removal...");
        var = 5;
        u.removeAll(ref var);
        u.print();

        Console.WriteLine("\nThe min value for integers is " + u.min(ref var));
        Console.WriteLine("The max value for integers is " + u.max(ref var));

        UnorderedArrayList<string> p = new UnorderedArrayList<string>();
        Console.WriteLine("\nThis is the list before removal..."); ;
        p.print();
        string cow = "cow";
        p.insert(ref cow);
        cow = "dog";
        p.insert(ref cow);
        cow = "cat";
        p.insert(ref cow);
        cow = "wolf";
        p.insert(ref cow);
        cow = "dog";
        p.insert(ref cow);
        cow = "whale";
        p.insert(ref cow);
        cow = "buffalo";
        p.insert(ref cow);
        cow = "monkey";
        p.insert(ref cow);
        cow = "walrus";
        p.insert(ref cow);
        p.print();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("This is the list after removal...");
        cow = "cow";
        p.removeAll(ref cow);
        p.print();

        Console.WriteLine("\nThe min value for strings is..." + p.min(ref cow));
        Console.WriteLine("The max value for strings is..." + p.max(ref cow));

        UnorderedArrayList<double> q = new UnorderedArrayList<double>();
        Console.WriteLine("\nThis is the list before removal...");
        q.print();
        double dub = 5.2;
        q.insert(ref dub);
        q.insert(ref dub);
        dub = 12.54;
        q.insert(ref dub);
        dub = 2.14;
        q.insert(ref dub);
        dub = 29.13;
        q.insert(ref dub);
        dub = 3.56;
        q.insert(ref dub);
        dub = 32.14;
        q.insert(ref dub);
        dub = 43.23;
        q.insert(ref dub);
        dub = 2.33;
        q.insert(ref dub);
        dub = 4.77;
        q.insert(ref dub);
        dub = 15.46;
        q.insert(ref dub);
        q.print();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("This is the list after removal...");
        dub = 5.2;
        q.removeAll(ref dub);
        q.print();

        Console.WriteLine("\nThe min value for double is " + q.min(ref dub));
        Console.WriteLine("The max value for double is " + q.max(ref dub));
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
}
using System;

namespace ArrayListADTNamespace
{
public interface ArrayListADT<T>
{
    // insert() method places one item in the list
    void insert(ref T item);
    // remove() method removes first instance of item in list
    int remove(ref T item);
    // print() method prints all items in list
    void print();
    // removal all method
    void removeAll(ref T item);
    // min method
    T min(ref T item);
    // max method
    T max(ref T item);
    void insertSort();
  }
  }
using System;
using ArrayListNamespace;
using ArrayListADTNamespace;

namespace UnorderedArrayListNamespace
{
public class UnorderedArrayList<T> : ArrayList<T>, ArrayListADT<T> where T: IComparable
{
    public UnorderedArrayList()
    {
    }

    public override void insert(ref T item)
    {
        list[length] = item;
        length++;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: @Tim Schmelter It is a type parameter correct? I don't think I can use it as a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list` is of type `T[]` meaning `list[i]` will return a `T`, but `temp` is an `int`. Try changing your `temp` variable to a `T` and using `CompareTo` instead of `list[j] > T`:

```
public void insertSort()
{
    T temp = list[0];
    int j;

    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++)
    {
       if (list[i].CompareTo(temp) < 0)
        {
            temp = list[i];
            j = i - 1;
            while (j >= 0 && list[j].CompareTo(temp) > 0)
            {
                list[j + 1] = list[j];
                j--;
            }
            list[j + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you really don't need to use the `ref` keyword on every parameter. `ref` and `out` allow your method to modify the value of the parameter and return that modified value back to caller—something that's almost never necessary. See [ref C# Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Attempted this, still gives me the same error messages. Only applies to the + operand now as well.

Comment: @Azzamean Oops, it should be `T temp; int j;`. See my updated answer.

Comment: For some reason I do. I do not know why, but it will not work if I don't use it. Assuming you are talking about the ref in the methods such as min, max, etc...

Comment: @Azzamean Well, in `min` and `max`, for example, you're not even using the parameters at all. For others like `remove`, you're not actually changing the value of the parameter at all, so it definitely shouldn't be needed. If you're saying it doesn't work, I suspect the error is somewhere else.

Comment: @ p.s.w.g use of unassigned local variable 'temp', but it did clear up a lot of those errors. Im taking a look at this now to see what its saying that error.

Comment: @Azzamean ahh, You probably just need `T temp = list[0]`. I have a feeling that was your intent anyway since your `for`-loop starts at 1.

Comment: @ p.s.w.g 'UnorderedArrayListNamespace.UnorderedArrayList<T>' does not implement interface member 'ArrayListADTNamespace.ArrayListADT<T>.max(ref T)' is the error when I remove it from min or max methods. Since it works when I have it in there I did not bother to see why since I was having trouble in other areas of the code.

Comment: Yea I was getting ready to post that was the exact change I did to get it to work when I saw you posted the T temp = list[0]. On the ref thing I still cannot understand that.

Comment: @Azzamean You should probably remove the `ref`'s from your `ArrayListADT` interface as well.